# How to highlight the whole selected cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, customization

Is there any way to highlight the whole selected cell?
some times if I want to delete a certain cell and if the code is long and cells are without output, it is hard to know which cell that you are selecting.
For example, in this simple file, I want to select a certain cell as seen:

[image]

If I want to select the second cell, I may make mistake and select the above or below cell (especially if the code is long).

is there any way to highlight the whole cell once I selected it from the right?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you may find it helpful to know that you can press `Ctrl + .` repeatedly to make progressively larger selections.

Comment: If you want something "nice", add some keyevents to `KeyEventsTranslation.tr` file to change/revert background colors///

Comment: @mfvonh thanks for this nice tip:). I am using what you have said but I thought it would be nice if I can get the cell highlighted when selected.

Comment: @rashed, I will try your suggestion. thanks

Comment: do you know guys how to suggest some features or ideas to Wolfram people?

Comment: support@wolfram.com or http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/. No idea if they will check for an MMA license or not.

Comment: Your tip is great @mfvonh but sometimes when using Ctrl+. I ended up over-selecting to a larger group and had no idea to return back to the smaller cell. Really wish MMA comes out with a more organic way of selecting cells.

Answer (score 10):

I agree that it can be hard to tell that you have selected the correct cell bracket and that having a global option to highlight the whole cell when it is selected would be good. But I don't know how to do that. What I have done to alleviate the problem is to set **Option Inspector > Global Preferences > Cell Options > Display Options > CellBracketOptions > "HoverColor"** to `RGBColor[1, 0, 0]`, which is red. With this setting, when I hover the mouse cursor over a cell bracket, it turns red, confirming that, if I click, this cell with the red bracket will be the one selected. It's nowhere as good as full-cell highlighting would be, but it does help.

[image: hover_color]

Comment: Nice one - had not noticed this option before. +1

Comment: good god this is amazing. MMA's design is incredible in some ways and in others it just makes me go WTF.

Comment: @seismatica. Welcome to the club:)

Comment: @m_goldberg - Thank you very much

Comment: @m_goldberg great idea:). thanks a lot. how about me? am I welcomed to the club:)

Comment: @Algohi. Do you have the same mixed emotions as seismtica when you use *Mathematica*? If you do, I am happy to extend my welcome to you, too.

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks. I don't really know what is the club you mean. I like Mathematica and I enjoy working with it. great thanks:)

Comment: @Algohi. It's the club for those who have a love-hate relationship with *Mathematica*

Comment: @m_goldberg yes I love Mathematica most of the time but also sometimes I feel upset and not happy about the way Mathematica work in some issues. you can consider me a member in the club if the case is like this:)

Answer (score 7):

**Initial approach**

The obvious thing to try is to give the [`Background`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Background) a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic) based on [`SelectedCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectedCells) / [`EvaluationCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationCell), but this didn't work. It seems that [`SelectedCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectedCells) doesn't get triggered when the mouse clicks the cell brackets.

After thinking about this for a while, I came up with the following idea. Give the notebook a [`NotebookEventActions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookEventActions) option that counts mouse clicks. Then, trigger the background dynamic object on changes in mouse clicks. This did work. Here are more details:

**NotebookEventActions**

```
SetOptions[
    InputNotebook[],
    NotebookEventActions -> {
        "MouseClicked" :> If[IntegerQ@i, i++, i=1],
        PassEventsDown->True
    }
]
```

Whenever the mouse is clicked in the notebook, the variable `i` is incremented (or initialized to 1 if it doesn't have a value). Then, the [`PassEventsDown`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PassEventsDown) is option is set to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True) so that you can actually click in the notebook. It's not really important that `i` is incremented, the important thing is that it changes for every mouse click. However, it doesn't hurt to have a mouse click counter.

**Stylesheet**

Next, we add a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic) background to "Input" cells. The relevant style data is:

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"],
    CellFrameMargins->0,
    Background->Dynamic @ If[
        And[
            IntegerQ[i],
            MemberQ[SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]], EvaluationCell[]],
            MatchQ[
                "CursorPosition" /. Developer`CellInformation[EvaluationCell[]],
                "CellBracket"
            ]
        ],
        LightBlue,
        None    
    ]
]
```

Here, I include `IntegerQ[i]` so that the body of the dynamic is triggered each time `i` changes, i.e., every time a mouse click occurs in the notebook. Then, determine whether the cell is included in [`SelectedCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectedCells). If it is, make sure the cursor is in the cell bracket (I think highlighting the cell while editing would be highly distracting). If the cell is selected and the cursor is in the cell bracket, than set the background to [`LightBlue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LightBlue), otherwise set it to [`None`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/None). The [`CellFrameMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellFrameMargins) option is included so that adding a background color doesn't change the size of the cell.

It is also possible to use `` Developer`CellInformation[InputNotebook[]] ``, as this will return cell information for all selected cells, including cursor position and the [`ExpressionUUID`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionUUID). Just check that the cursor is in the bracket, and the cell's [`ExpressionUUID`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionUUID) is included in the list of cell information.

**Package**

It would be good if we put the variable `i` into a private context. Also, it would be nice to have the stylesheet and notebook modified appropriately when a package is loaded. So, here is the above code put into a package:

```
BeginPackage["HighlightSelectedCells`"];

Begin["`Private`"];

SetOptions[
    InputNotebook[],
    CellEventActions -> {
        "MouseClicked" :> If[IntegerQ[i], i++, i=0],
        PassEventsDown->True
    }
]

SetOptions[InputNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Input"],
            CellFrameMargins->0,
            Background->Dynamic @ If[
                And[
                    IntegerQ[i],
                    MemberQ[SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]], EvaluationCell[]],
                    MatchQ[
                        "CursorPosition" /. Developer`CellInformation[EvaluationCell[]],
                        "CellBracket"
                    ]
                ],
                LightBlue,
                None    
            ]
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Put the above code into the file "HighlightSelectedCells.m" in a location on your path. Then:

```
<<HighlightSelectedCells`
```

will load the package. Here is an animated gif showing how it works:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant Solution!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem but if you want to select a particular cell (without mistakenly selecting others), just **put your horizontal bar**--whatever it's called--**above or below the cell**, whichever position that's more convenient to you (for example, for an output cell, it makes sense to put the bar below it instead of navigating up to the narrow strip between the input and output cell).

Then, you can **press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to select the cell above/below the bar**. The nice thing about this is it will always select only one cell even if this cell belongs to a group or is joined by a hidden cell. To select other cells, just continue pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: Another neat thing that I found by accident just now is that once you select a cell (either by clicking on its right-side bracket or by using the Shift method in my answer), you can just press Up or Down (without holding Shift) to navigate to the correct cell in the event that you found you'd just selected the wrong cell.

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete a certain cell, but you are unsure whether you selected the right bracket:

Click the bracket, select `Style` and then `Title`. If you hit the wrong bracket, select `Input`.

Another way (if you deleted the wrong cell) is to immediately press  `Ctrl + z`

Comment: I can also use Alt+4 (or any number from 1 to 7) to quickly change the style of the selected cell. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Algohi - very nice ! Alt+1 to highlight and Alt+9 to go back to `InputForm` :)