# Highlight cells selected feature : Request?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization

I always delete more cells than I want to. This is because every time I choose the cells, I am not looking at the corresponding code belonging to that cell bracket (why? because Mathematica doesn't highlight what I am selecting). When you have multiple lines of code (single-celled) and you want to delete some at a stretch, you may accidentally delete one which you dint want to.

Is there an option in v.11 ? Or is this a feature that must be requested. Irrespective of all these, this should be a default feature.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMQxP.png) Highlights cell brackets, but not cell:
[image: 1]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZy9x.png) Different FONT STYLE with cut+paste on same notebook
[image]

Comment: If you select a cell bracket, the correspond code contained within the cell bracket must be highlighted. This will visually help the user to understand what section of code is selected.

Comment: See my answer to [How to highlight the whole selected cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51293/45431). All you need to do is to change Background to FontColor, and change colors.

Answer (score 2):

So I disagree that this should be a default feature (I think it would interrupt my flow, at least). But it's not so tough to get this in as a default feature.

If you only want it to affect your notebooks going forward, you can make your own stylesheet where you implement this and then set:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, DefaultStyleDefinitions]
```

to that stylesheet.

Alternatively we can take advantage of the fact that `` FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath `` will scan `$UserBaseDirectory` before the system dirs.

That means we can make a whole-sale copy of `"Default.nb"` in the `$UserBaseDirectory` and just muck-about with that:

```
$userBaseStyles =
  FileNameJoin@{
    $UserBaseDirectory,
    "SystemFiles",
    "FrontEnd",
    "StyleSheets",
    "Default.nb"
    };
With[{defStyles = 
    FrontEndExecute@
     FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["Default.nb", "StyleSheetPath"]},
  CopyFile[defStyles, $userBaseStyles]
  ];
SetOptions[
 NotebookOpen[$userBaseStyles],
 {
  Editable -> True,
  Saveable -> True
  }
 ]
```

There should then be a way to add in your defintion. Here's a first guess, although it should be possible to do this with things in the `` FEPrivate` `` context. (when I figure that out I'll post it)

#### Update: FEPrivate confusion

by what I know about the `` FEPrivate` `` context this ought to be working:

```
FEPrivate`If[
 FEPrivate`MemberQ[
  FrontEnd`Cells[
   FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]]
   ],
  FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[]
  ],
 Hue[.6, .05, 1],
 Inherited
 ]
```

But for reasons I don't understand it is not. Obviously it doesn't work with `` FE`Evaluate ``, because neither `` FronEnd`Cells `` nor `` FrontEnd`EvaluationCell `` work with it, but I thought in the past it had resolved such things fine, anyway.

#### Original:

```
FontColor -> 
 Dynamic[If[MemberQ[SelectedCells[], EvaluationCell[]], Blue, 
   Inherited]]
```

To the cell using Command-Shift-E (on Mac) or Cell > Show Expression

Then restart and you have your change.